# How can I catch each character in a string with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to get each character in a string so that I can animate them individually without touching the html.

For example :

```
<h1>I am a title</h1>
```

The objective is to catch all the letters in it so that I can make them appear one after another with an animation and a transition that increments on 0.1s. The problem is, I have no idea how to do that ! I think we need the get the textNode in the h1 and then splice it with a forEach loop that get each character, but i can't write it, i don't know the method to do that since i'm a beginner with jquery. Can anyone help me out with this one ?

Comment: What have you tried? Add your code here.

Comment: This might be helpful, more generally: https://www.codecademy.com/learn/jquery

Comment: i hadn't tried anything that was in that direction, i had no idea how to write the code ! Now with all the answers and Soviut's solution i can see perfectly how that works !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do a type-on effect you can take the string from the h1 and then use an asnyc loop to slowly reintroduce the letters.

```js
var text = $('h1').text();
var pos = 0;
var delay = 200; // milliseconds

function typeon() {
  pos++;
  var typedText = text.substr(0, pos);
  $('h1').text(typedText);
  
  if (pos < text.length) {
    // call itself after delay, an async loop
    setTimeout(typeon, delay);
  }
}

// start
typeon();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>This is a Type-on Effect</h1>
```

Comment: thank you this is exactly what i was looking for and it works great !

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this suit your needs?

```
$('h1').text().split(''); // == ['I', ' ', 'a', 'm', ' ', 'a', ' ', 't', 'i', 't', 'l', 'e'];

$('h1')
  .text()
  .split('')
  .forEach(function(c){
    // Do something with each letter
  });
```

Which you could also do without jQuery like this:

```js
document
  .querySelector('h1')
  .textContent
  .split('')
  .forEach(function(c){
    // Do something with each letter here
  });
```

```html
<h1>I am a title</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
var str=$("h1").text();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var h1Content = jQuery("h1").text(); // You may want to use an id or class to have more control over this
var h1ContArr = h1Content.split(""); // You now have an array holding each character inside <h1></h1>
```

Now you can use a loop on `h1ContArr`

Answer (score 0):

First you have to get the content of your title.

```
var title = document.querySelector('h1').textContent
```

Then I suggest you to do a loop, that will display letter by letter your variable.

```
for (var i = 0; i < title.length; i++) {
        tmp = title.substring(i);
        $('#WhereYouDisplay').text(tmp);
    };
```

Please try to do something like that, and tell us if you succeed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one method:

First, make sure the h1 is empty: `<h1></h1>`

Then, add a span inside with just one letter: `<h1><span>I</span></h1>`

Animate the span as per your requirement

Then change the innerHTML of the h1 such that the earlier letter is outside the span, and the next letter is in the span:

`<h1>I <span>a</span></h1>`

`<h1>I a<span>m</span></h1>`

`<h1>I am <span>a</span></h1>`

etc..

Here's some reference code:

```
var str = "I am a title"
str.split("").forEach(function (d, idx, arr) {
    var _retStr = '<h1>' + arr.slice(0,idx).join("") + '<span>' + arr[idx] + '</span><h1>';
    $('h1').innerHTML = _retStr;
});
```